# Fullscreen mode for a WebGL application on Chrome Mobile

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webgl

I have a WebGL application. I would like it to go to fullscreen mode when ran on Chrome Mobile. Is this possible and if so, how? I searched around the internet and all I could come up with was this post http://chromespot.com/2013/01/26/full-screen-chrome-beta-android/. On my phone, Chrome Mobile Beta doesn't open this experiment in fullscreen mode, though.